# How to display used coupon code in order details page in admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin-panel, coupon-codes, order-details

**I need to show used coupon code in backend order details page**. In my searches i found `coupon code does not store with order details`.

So I was thinking to save coupon code somewhere just after order placement & then used these values in order details page.

**Is there any better way doing this.** Please help.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that coupon code is displayed in admin in totals block. If you are having some customization in there, then you might not be able to see that, but in a default Magento, it is saved with order and is displayed in admin as well.

Comment: Is there any progress on this as I have same question I also want to show the coupon codes in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceContainer name="order_totals">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Totals" name="coupon_rules"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Totals.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;
class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{
    public function initTotals()
    {
        $order = $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
        $salesruleIds = explode(',', $order->getAppliedRuleIds());
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $ruleNames = array();
        foreach ($salesruleIds as $key => $ruleId) { 
            $rule=$objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($ruleId); 
            $ruleNames[] = $rule->getName();
        }
        $rules = implode(",",$ruleNames);
        $total = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'coupon_rules',
                'field' => 'coupon_rules',
                'value' => abs($order->getDiscountAmount()),
                'base_value'=> abs($order->getDiscountAmount()),
                'label' => __($rules)
            ]
        );
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        $parent->addTotal($total,'subtotal');
        return $this;
    }
}
```